# Package pillow installed but unable to be imported

Tags: python3, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have anaconda with python 3 installed in windows 7 64 bits. Due to inexperience, I don't know why I ended up with a custom version of anaconda as shown

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anaconda                  custom           py36h363777c_0
```

When I run `conda list`, I can see the package `pillow` installed as shown

```
pep8                      1.7.1                    py36_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py36_0
pillow                    5.4.1            py36hdc69c19_0
pip                       18.1                     pypi_0    pypi
pluggy                    0.9.0                    py36_0
```

However, when I run `import pillow` or `import Pillow` in Jupyterlab, I got the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pillow'
```

Confusingly, I can run `import PIL` in Jupyterlab, although I can't see the `PIL` package installed.

Then I see an [instruction](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#warnings) below which seems contradicting
[conflict between Pillow and PIL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2xwW.jpg)

Could you please advise what's happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pillow is a fork of PIL (the Python Imaging Library) and therefore has retained PIL's syntax for importing. However, more broadly speaking, Python doesn't require that package names be reflected in their `import` statements and thus they can differ significantly (e.g. BeautifulSoup imports as `bs` or `bs4`, depending upon the version of BeautifulSoup installed). Given that, it isn't uncommon to see `import` statements that do not match their package names in Python.

Comment: Could you please clarify then if `Pillow` is the same as `pillow` so I don't need to install either `pillow` or `Pillow` as it's already installed in my environment and `PIL` package is no longer maintained? Thanks

Comment: [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) currently appears to be at version 6.0.0 and [PyPi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=pillow) doesn't list a `pillow` package, just `Pillow`. Anaconda is also often a bit behind, and since you were able to `import PIL`, it seems these are the same packages (i.e. `Pillow` is already in your environment). So you shouldn't need to install anything. To the issue of `PIL`, it is no longer maintained to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: No problem. You are welcome. =)